# Will using GPT delete the encryption?

Tags: partitioning

New hdd, no data; using as storage hdd only - no os. I just encrypted my hdd and it has no partition. If I do the following, will the encryption be deleted? The size of the hdd is too large for "fdisk". Below is an example of someone else trying to do the same thing with their ouput afterwards.

```
I encrypted using the following format: 
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdX
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdX external_disk
mkfs /dev/mapper/external_disk
cryptsetup luksCLose external_disk
```

I created a partition using the folling:

sudo parted /dev/sda

Output:
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted)

Creates a new GPT disklabel i.e. partition table:

mklabel gpt

Next, set the default unit to TB, enter:

unit TB

To create a 2TB partition size, enter:

mkpart primary 0.00TB 2.00TB

To print the current partitions, enter:

print

Sample outputs:

Model: ATA ST33000651AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2.00TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      0.00TB  2.00TB  2.00TB  ext4         primary

Quit and save the changes, enter:

quit

Use the mkfs.ext4 command to format the file system, enter:

mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1

```
update: I got a similar output except that my logical partition size was 512bytes and the physical was (like) 4068. 
But now it seems my encryption is gone as I can mount and open the partition without a password.
```

Comment: The encryption will not be deleted in the way that after this procedure the data will be unencrypted. But the data will likely be no more accessible at all, no matter if you know the password or not.

Comment: How did you encrypt the HDD exactly?

Comment: If you did not partition at all, then data will be deleted. You probably started write at beginning of drive where partition table info normally is and then writing partition table overwrites beginning of your data, and then rest will not be readable. Back up all your data & then restore it after repartitioning.

Comment: "I just encrypted my hdd and it has no partition." This makes no sense. You mean the encryption process broke the partitioning, or...?? Your OS cannot write to a drive that doesn't have at least one partition.

Comment: @grawity cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdX; 
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdX external_disk; 
mkfs /dev/mapper/external_disk; 
cryptsetup luksCLose external_disk

Comment: @Tetsujin I edited my question text - answers your questions. Thanks.

Comment: @oldfred  I edited my question text. Thx.

Comment: After doing all of that, I was just able to open my hdd "WITHOUT" being asked for the password. I'm guessing I deleted the encryption I did before creating a partition and formatting...?

Comment: You used LVM which I only know a little about. I gather you can directly install it to a drive, but that is unusual. You normally set the LVM & encryption up inside a partition. Some systems still want a separate /boot partition, but I believe grub can be configured to open the encrypted LVM to boot. Do not know any details.

Comment: @tetsujin Linux has no problem writing to a raw (unpartitioned) drive - its just a block device. While its best practice to partition a drive, and required for certain operations - like booting and maybe some auto mounting operations , there is no technical limitation preventing operations (including formatting) the raw disk.

Comment: @topencrypt You overwrote the LUKS volume by creating a partition table and formatting a new partition as ext4. The reason you didn't get asked for a password is that the new filesystem isn't encrypted

Comment: @Torin Yes, you are correct. Redid it, good now. Thanks

Comment: @oldfred With the correct commands, the partition was created first and then the rest worked. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

With the schema written in the question, GPT partitioning was not needed and not used. The schema there created the needed partition.